# ion-toggle ng-change does not trigger properly with controller + service structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've created a list of toggles to select bluetooth devices and connect it, and I've created a controller.js and service.js for them. However, the `ng-change`only triggers when ion-toggles first loaded in view, and were not triggering for changes afterwards.

Here is my snippet of `setting.html`:

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in devicesList"
            ng-model="item.checked"
            ng-change="connectDevice(devicesList)">
     {{ item.address }}
</ion-toggle>
```

and here is my `settingController.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('i18n.setting').controller('SettingController', SettingController);
    SettingController.$inject = ['$scope','SettingService'];

    function SettingController($scope, SettingService) {
        $scope.devicesList = [];
        $scope.scanDevices = SettingService.scanDevices($scope.devicesList);
        $scope.connectDevice = SettingService.connectDevice($scope.devicesList);
    };

})();
```

and here is my `settingService.js`:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('i18n.setting').service('SettingService', SettingService);

    SettingService.$inject = [];
    function SettingService(){
        var self = this;

        this.scanDevices = function(devicesCollection) {
            window.bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired(function(devices) {
                console.log("in discoverUnpaired callback, setting page");
                devices.forEach(function(device) {
                    console.log(device.name);
                    device.checked = false;
                    devicesCollection.push(device);
                });

            }, function(error) {
                console.log("in discoverUnpaired error function");
                console.log(error);
            });
        };

        this.connectDevice = function(devicesCollection) {
            console.log(devicesCollection);
            console.log("In connectDevice");
            for (var i =0; i<devicesCollection.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(devicesCollection[i].id + " " + devicesCollection[i].checked);
                if (devicesCollection[i].checked == true)
                {
                    console.log(devicesCollection[i].name);
                    window.bluetoothSerial.connect(devicesCollection[i].address,
                        function(data) {console.log("This device is"+macaddress); console.log(data);},
                        function(error) {console.log(error);});
                }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

And if I define this function directly in `settingController.js`, it's working properly and can detect every change of the toggle. Also, I noticed that my `scanDevices` function will be triggered even if I don't click the button. I don't know why is it. Will there be someone tell me what cause is it? Any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller should put the service functions on the scope; not invocations of the service functions.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('i18n.setting').controller('SettingController', SettingController);
    SettingController.$inject = ['$scope','SettingService'];

    function SettingController($scope, SettingService) {
        $scope.devicesList = [];
        //$scope.scanDevices = SettingService.scanDevices($scope.devicesList);
        $scope.scanDevices = SettingService.scanDevices;
        //$scope.connectDevice = SettingService.connectDevice($scope.devicesList);
        $scope.connectDevice = SettingService.connectDevice;
    };

})();
```

Since the `scanDevices` function has no `return` statement, `scanDevices($scope.deviceList)` returns `undefined`. Thus `$scope.scanDevices` was getting set to `undefined`.

---

### Update

> Can you also explain why scanDevices get invoked before I press the Scan button?
>
> Which was bind to:
>
> ```
> <button class="button button-stable"
>         ng-click="scanDevices(devicesList)">Scan Devices
> </button>
> ```

By binding an **invocation** of the function to the scope variable instead of the **function** itself:

```
//ERRONEOUS
$scope.scanDevices = SettingService.scanDevices($scope.devicesList);

//CORRECT
$scope.scanDevices = SettingService.scanDevices;
```

The expression `SettingService.scanDevices($scope.devicesList)` invokes the function **before** the button is clicked. And assigns `undefined` to the `$scope.scanDevices` variable.

Comment: Can you also explain why `scanDevices` get invoked before I press the `Scan` button? Which was bind to `<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="scanDevices(devicesList)">Scan Devices</button>`?

Comment: After I put the service functions on the scope, I still can't get the `$scope.devicesList` in `connectDevice`.

Comment: Nevermind, it's my problem, I shouldn't do that in the callback.